# Can’t set StringCollection’ string

Tags: c#, stringcollection

I have code

```
PrinterSettings set = new PrinterSettings();
set.PrinterName = set.InstalledPrinters[0];
```

I can’t compile it because of error (Google translate): it is not possible to access this via an instance link.

How to fix it?

Comment: If you have an error message, usually this have also an error number. The best thing to do is to start your browser and search for that error code.

Comment: Here the result for CS0176: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0176

Answer (score 2):

[InstalledPrinters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters) is a static property, so use the class name and not the instance name to access it:

```
set.PrinterName = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[0];
```

Note that this will crash if there are no printers installed, so better check if `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters` is not empty.